# Retrieve Image From Program Resources

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to add a image to an image list from a PNG stored in the program resource file. How might I go about doing that at runtime?

Comment: take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg418542.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
imageList1.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.myImage);
```